# Crystal report problem

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net

I have a MSSQL database that transformed from a computer to a new computer for a application. In new system i can get all data form the database and manipulate over them.

But the problem is that when I want to make using CRYSTAL REPORT using that database the crystal report ask for a username and password and it displays SERVER name form the previous system.

Please make me rid from this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand your question correctly, open the report and right-click the Database Fields item in the Field Explorer.  Click Set Database Location... Point your report at the new server.